# Correct Length of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsstring

I am working on my first iPhone application, in that application I have to calculate the length of NSString, I have tried the available methods and solutions here on SO but for the length is always wrong. For example for a string "test4" NSString.length returns 12 while it should return 5.

I have tried NSString's length property and lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding but both return the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
NSString *string = @"test4";
[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // returns 12
string.length; // returns 12
```

**Complete Code**

```
+(NSString *)AES256Encrypt:(NSString *)data withKey:(NSString *)rawkey{

    rawkey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"123456789023456", rawkey];
    rawkey = [rawkey substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 32)];

    NSData *key = [rawkey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *iv = [key subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 16)];
    const char *bytes = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%d", data.length); // prints 12
    data = [self encode:bytes length:data.length];

    NSData *rawData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

    NSData *encrypted = [rawData dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:key initializationVector:iv options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:&status];

    NSString *text = [encrypted base64EncodedString];
    return text;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the relevent code segment where you calculated the length?

Comment: everybody is asking for code... hmmmm, seems like a pattern here!

Comment: Done, added the code I am using.

Comment: Just call NSUInteger count = [string length]; to get what you are after.

Comment: @Luke `[string length]` is exactly the same as `string.length`...

Comment: Yes, and it does work, correctly returning 5, which is what the OP wants. Therefore something else is going on or the OP has done something wrong.

Comment: Please check the complete code snippet.

Comment: Call NSLog at the start of the method and see if it's 12.  Also log the contents as well to check if the string is actually 5 characters.

Comment: Aparently data has a length of 12.

Comment: it is 12 from the start, and printing the data results in test4

Comment: @Macmade how that helps?

Comment: You all notice that NSString stores its characters in 4-byte `unichar`s, right?

Comment: If any answer helped you should mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *myString = @"test4";
int i =myString.length;
NSLog(@"Count =%d",i);
```

which print `Count = 5`